# how to put json string into list in java

Tags: java, json, collections

I'm getting a `JSON array` in string like

```
[ { "id":"ca.Primary_Diagnosis_Dt",
    "field":"ca.Primary_Diagnosis_Dt",
    "type":"date",
    "input":"text",
    "operator":"not_equal",
    "value":"2016/06/07"
  },
  { "id":"ca.Clinical_Stage",
    "field":"ca.Clinical_Stage",
    "type":"integer",
    "input":"select",
    "operator":"equal",
    "value":"I"
  }
]
```

i just want to save the value of id ,operator and value in `LIST` please help

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: rules : JSON.stringify(json.rules)

Comment: this i used in ajax call

Comment: So you are using JavaScript and not Java?

Comment: from ajaxcall i send this to servlet and from getter i got above value as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online : **[Working code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=compile_java_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcEpHNUwzVGhkUGc)**

First create a class to store your values :

```
class Data{
  String id;
  String operator;
  String value;
}
```

Then iterate over the json :

```
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray("[JSON Stirng]");
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
        Data data = new Data();

        data.id = jsonObj.getString("id");
        data.operator = jsonObj.getString("operator");
        data.value = jsonObj.getString("value");

        dataList.add(data);
    }
```

Now `dataList` has your data!

P.S. : Use getter/setters in `Data` class

JAR : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Answer (score 1):

1. Use any JSON parsor eg: [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to create an arraylist of this particular json
2. Iterate the arraylist
3. Save it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a JSon library such as `org.glassfish.javax.json`

In Maven use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then read the string to a JsonArray:

```
JsonArray ja = Json.createReader(new StringReader(input)).readArray();
```

Then iterate over the list, map the objects to a new objects with just the values you need:

```
List<JsonObject> list = ja.stream()
                          .map(o -> (JsonObject) o)
                          .map(jo -> Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                         .add("id", jo.getJsonString("id"))
                                         .add("operator", jo.getJsonString("operator"))
                                         .add("value", jo.getJsonString("value")).build())
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In case you could not use `JsonObject` as output, you may use a value object instead - just like Himanshu Tyagi proposed - and map the values to that object.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think, the JSON should be parsed into a `List<Map<String,String>>`. This can be done using `Jackson`. Following is a method that converts a JSON string into `List<Map<String,String>>`:

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> toList(String json) throws IOException {

    List<Map<String, String>> listObj;

    ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    listObj = MAPPER.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>() {
    });

    return listObj;
}
```

If you have created a POJO class for it then you can use:

```
public static List<PojoClass> toList(String json) throws IOException {

    List<PojoClass> listObj;

    ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    listObj = MAPPER.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ArrayList<PojoClass>>() {
    });

    return listObj;
}
```

Maven dependency for `Jackson`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```