# Java - How can i read json file and put values into array

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I have this JSON file called `city.list.json`, containing objects like these:

```
{
"id": 707860,
"name": "Hurzuf",
"country": "UA",
"coord": {
  "lon": 34.283333,
  "lat": 44.549999
}}
```

How can I put name's value into array?

This is the code I've tried:

```
String name = null;

    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray("[JSON String]");
    ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
        Data data = new Data();

        data.name = jsonObj.getString("name");


        dataList.add(data);
    }
```

But it gives me errors on data saying "Constructor Data in class Data cannot applied to given types"

Comment: I've tried the code in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052384/how-to-put-json-string-into-list-in-java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to achieve this task:

```
String input = yourSampleJson;
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String,Object> inputPojo = new HashMap<>();
inputPojo = gson.fromJson(input, inputPojo.class); // This map now contains the representation of your JSON.
```

I generally prefer having a POJO class which represents your JSON structure something as :

```
Class DanielePojo {
  Integer id;
  String name;
  String country;
  Coord coord; // This is another class similar to this POJO which is represented as Object in your JSON
 // Then your getters and setters
}
```

Then you can convert JSON into Pojo object directly without having a MAP as an intermediate object.

```
DanielePojo pojo = new GSON.fromJSON(input,DanielePojo.class);
```